# Imported content is empy Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the price of an item in my Sheet but I am unable to get it using IMPORTXML command as it keeps returning the error "Imported content empty"

I'm trying to retrieve the highlighted number on the image.

Site link: https://csgostash.com/sticker/3666/Battle-Scarred-Holo

My code: =IMPORTXML("https://csgostash.com/sticker/3666/Battle-Scarred-Holo","/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSFOU.jpg)/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSFOU.jpg)/a/span[2]")

[The image is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSFOU.jpg)

It would be great if anyone could help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML for that website has no visual hierarchy, so it's tough to plow down through it. But this is what I arrived at:

`=IMPORTXML("https://csgostash.com/sticker/3666/Battle-Scarred-Holo","/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/span[2]")`